# sum of different sequences in a list

Tags: python, dataframe

In one of my dataframe columns, I have some values I would like to summarize when they are above a certain value. When the value drops below, the summarization should stop. Once the value is above again, I would like to summarize once more.

Let’s see, I created a sample of my dataframe:

```
start = datetime.datetime(2021,1,1,0,0,0)
end = datetime.datetime(2021,1,1,12,0,0)
time = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=pd.DateOffset(hours=1))
pred = pd.DataFrame(time)
pred['predicted_load'] = [99.0, 98.0, 110.0, 110.0, 180.0, 90.0, 
80.0, 110.0, 110.0, 180.0, 90.0, 90.0, 90.0]
```

I would like to loop and sum the sequences where the ‘predicted_load’ is above 100.0 and get the index for this value.

So somehow my result should be something like this (structured in some smart way):

```
sequence 1: 110.0 + 110.0 + 180.0 = 400.0, index (start) = 2
sequence 2: 110.0 + 110.0 + 180.0 = 400.0, index (start) = 7
```

I have tried in a generic way to solve this, but I don't know how to jump to the next sequence and store the results and index as I go along:

```
over_lim, tot = [],0
for value in pred['predicted_load']:
    if value >= 100.0:
        over_lim.append(value)
        tot += value
        print (tot)
```

Comment: You maybe want to try using next() function in "else" condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the index in your original dataframe has no gaps, you can get your start indices by looking for the gaps in the index of the reduced dataframe that contains only the high load values:

```py
high_load_index = pred[pred.predicted_load >= 100].index
start_index = [high_load_index[0]]

for i, next_i in zip(high_load_index[:-1], high_load_index[1:]):
    if next_i - i > 1:
        start_index.append(next_i)
        
print(start_index)
```

```
[2, 7]
```

Then you can use these start indices to build up your sequences of consecutive high load predictions:

```py
high_sequences = []
current_sequence = []

for i in high_load_index:
    if i in start_index[1:]:
        high_sequences.append(current_sequence)
        current_sequence = []
    current_sequence.append(pred.predicted_load.loc[i])
high_sequences.append(current_sequence)

print(high_sequences)
```

```
[[110.0, 110.0, 180.0], [110.0, 110.0, 180.0]]
```

Now getting the sums over consecutive high load predictions is easy:

```py
high_sums = [sum(seq) for seq in high_sequences]
print(high_sums)
```

```
[400.0, 400.0]
```